How can I improve performance of this row_number() ranking window function query?
Table user_power_rank:



name
type
pk




id
string
1


userid
integer
0


power
integer
0


atime
integer
0



Indexes of this table:



index name
columns




i_power_desc_atime_asc
power desc, atime asc


i_id_power
id, power



Query to get user rank:
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id,power,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY power DESC, atime ASC) ranking
  FROM user_power_rank
) WHERE id="the-data-id"

Run time of this query:



data count
avg query time(ms)




10000
17.81


50000
101.32


100000
218.69



Performance is bad. Query plan:



id
parent
detail




2
0
CO-ROUTINE SUBQUERY 1


5
2
CO-ROUTINE SUBQUERY 3


9
5
SCAN user_rank_power USING INDEX i_power_desc_atime_asc


24
2
SCAN SUBUERY 3


63
0
SCAN SUBQUERY 1



How do I optimize performance?

Why do you do a 2 step request and not just 1 request with the where directly done in it? It would make the request less expensive if most lines are filtered out.

@JérômeRichard, because it's the global row_number() that OP is after. The query is correct, and the query plan is also optimal: At worst a full table scan is required to establish the rank; this is done walking the index, and yielding the one row where id=? as soon as it comes along.
If the table is read-heavy, it might we worth the cost to update the ranking (for all rows) using a trigger.

Ok. I wonder if the problem is not the SQLite implementation itself... I mean assuming your ID strings are <=8 bytes and you use 64-bit integers, the DB with 100000 rows should take only few MiB. So the operation cannot be memory bound (<1% of the bandwidth). I don't see why the operation would be compute-bound either. That being said, I assume the indexes are stored in memory, but this is apparently not the case from what I can read. Thus, if they are not and you have HDD, then this can be very slow. Even a bit with an SSD, this is not great (though far better). It makes things latency bound.

Is this Ok for you to use an in-memory database? If so, then can you try that just to check the IO latency is the issue or not.

@JérômeRichard yes, this is an in-memory database

Since your ranking is simply the global row_number(), it is equivalent to the number of rows that do sort "above". Instead of establishing the row_number() for all rows and then picking one result, we can count the number of rows that sort "above" that row for that exact sort-order; that number of rows is the value row_number() would have had.
SELECT id, power,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM user_power_rank AS inner
        WHERE (inner.power > user_power_rank.power
               OR (inner.power = user_power_rank.power
                   AND inner.atime <= user_power_rank.atime))) AS ranking
FROM user_power_rank
WHERE id = ?;

For 200,000 rows in user_power_rank the above query executes in 0.04s instead of 0.24s; for 1,000,000 rows it executes in 0.18s instead of 1.6s. Your mileage may vary depending on values for power are distributed.
One needs to be careful about how NULL-values would have been treated by ORDER BY compared to >/<, if NULL-values in power/atime are allowed at all.
Notice that in the construction of this query

inner.power > user_power_rank.power is equivalent to OVER (ORDER BY power DESC)
OR (inner.power = user_power_rank.power AND inner.atime <= user_power_rank.atime) is equivalent to OVER (..., atime ASC), but only for those values where power does not establish an order (because the values are equal).

Also notice that with the original query there is ambiguity with respect to the value of ranking if there are multiple rows with the same (power, atime)-values; this would have been solved by OVER (ORDER BY power DESC, atime ASC, id) (notice id at the bottom of the sort-tree) to guarantee unambiguous order. This ambiguity is preserved with this query, which may cause it to return different result than OP's query. This is not an error, the exact sort-order had been ambiguous to begin with.

thanks! this SQL can improve a lot of query performance. Actually, i use this SQL in my program now. As another option, i am trying to write a "skip-list", hope it can provide much better performance than SQL solution.

@Ace.Yin, if this answers the question, please mark the question as answered...
